# How to type loop that iterates over an array of mixed

Tags: php, psalm-php

Given this code (https://psalm.dev/r/156e52eb66):

```php
<?php

function keys(): array
{
  return ['foo', 'bar'];
}

// no lines above can be changed

foreach (keys() as $k) {
  echo gettype($k);
}
```

how would one type it assuming the `keys` function is not under our control (in a different project) and it effectively returns an array of `mixed` (`array<array-key, mixed>`).

So, one may only change the loop and around it.

Is it even possible?

**UPD**: I reported https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/issues/2025

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve? You want to know what type the different elements in the array is?

Comment: The library method returns an array of values of type `mixed`, so every array value may be of any valid php type. Check the provided psalm link, the warning is what I need to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right this might help you:

```
foreach (array_keys(keys()) as $k) {
 echo gettype(keys()[$k])."\n";
}
```

Comment: Oh boy. I must admit it type checks, but isn't it ugly as hell? Who would run something like that in production

Comment: For sure it is). I would not run it in production but for this psalm case it works.

Comment: Also check that I updated the question with a link to a bug report, and psalm dev team kind of agreed it should be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop to fix the warning.

```
$keys = keys();
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $keys); $i++ ) {
  echo gettype( $keys[$i] );
}
```

Here is the link in Psalm https://psalm.dev/r/20c1cbab73

Comment: @zerkms Please check now.

Comment: Yep, counts as a solution. The variation of the other answer though. +1 nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of [psalm](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm).

Refer to [Github: INFO: MixedAssignment - Cannot assign to a mixed type | when using string array key #1281](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/commit/6033345694727d7c3cf84adc76507c3785ed0295),

And it has been fixed by [muglug](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/commits?author=muglug) in this [commit 6033345694727d7c3cf84adc76507c3785ed0295](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/commit/6033345694727d7c3cf84adc76507c3785ed0295)

Comment: If it was fixed half a year ago - it must be already deployed to the psalm.dev repl